# daemonize of a process?

Tags: c, process

I'm learning apue and I try to daemonize a process according to the code sample in apue. The code is as follows:

```
#include <syslog.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int damonize(const char *cmd)
{
    int i, fd0, fd1, fd2;
    pid_t pid;
    struct rlimit rl;
    struct sigaction sa;

    umask(0);

    if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl) < 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(pid != 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    setsid();

    sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;

    if(sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL) < 0)
    {
        return 3;
    }

    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        return 4;
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    if(chdir("/") < 0)
    {
        return 5;
    }

    if(rl.rlim_max == RLIM_INFINITY)
    {
        rl.rlim_max = 1024;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < rl.rlim_max; i++)
    {
        close(i);
    }

    fd0 = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    fd1 = dup(0);
    fd2 = dup(0);

    openlog(cmd, LOG_CONS, LOG_DAEMON);
    if(fd0 != 0 || fd1 != 1 || fd2 != 2)
    {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "unexpected file descriptors %d %d %d\n", fd0, fd1, fd2);
        return 6;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int id;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
    id = damonize("ls");
    fprintf(fp, "%d", id);
    fclose(fp);
    exit(0);
}
```

I run the above program and use `ps -axj`, but there's no daemon process created by the program, and threre's no output in the file `test.txt`. My question is

What's wrong in my code? What causes the above two problems?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that your program is oversophisticated (if such a word exists in English). You are spawning one child process, exit parents, then the child spawns another child and exits. The child of the child is then closing all possible (even not opened) file descriptors, then it opens "/dev/null" and redirect standard input, output and error there. The "daemonisation" is finished and your program tries to write some number into a file "fp" in the main function. However, this `fp` have been closed long time ago in `daemonize`.

In other words, the main problem is that your `daemonize` function is closing all possible file descriptors in the loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < rl.rlim_max; i++) close(i);
```

However, if you want to daemonize a process why not to start with a simple solution and once it works you can add features while keeping it working. For example if you start with:

```
int daemonize() {
    pid_t   pid;

    pid = fork();  
    if (pid > 0) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    if (pid < 0) printf("Can't fork\n");
    return(pid);
}
```

Then you can add code for closing standard input `close(STDIN_FILENO);` before `return`, and so on. After each modification test if it is still working.

Comment: the code is presented in the book advanced programming in unix

Comment: I just want to make the two questions out

Answer (score 0):

You won't see the daemonized process because it doesn't stick around. After it tries writing to the file, it exits.

But it won't write to the file, because your daemonize routine closes every file handle (and that's what `fopen()` uses under the hood). Try opening the file in `main()` after `daemonize()`, or in the loop closing all file descriptors, exclude the one associated with the file using `fileno()`.

Comment: Then how could I make the progress stick around?

Comment: Well, what do you want it to do after it has written to the file? Trivially you could make it call `sleep(1)` in an infinite loop.

Comment: I want to the process to deal with requests from clients, many applications work in this manner, such as `memcached`

Comment: Indeed. Then you will need to write the code for it to do that, rather than write to a file and then exit, which is what it does at the moment.